# Склейка массивов в numpy

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Есть два трехмерных массива, например:

```
[[[1,2,3][7,8,9]] 

[[4,5,6][3,2,1]]]
```

и

```
[[[3,2,1][1,7,2]] 

[[7,1,5][4,1,8]]]
```

Как их склеить, чтобы получиь на выходе следующий массив:

```
[[[1,2,3][7,8,9][3,2,1][1,7,2]] 

[[7,1,5][4,1,8] [4,5,6][3,2,1]]]
```

Comment: Что-то непонятное у вас, а не массивы... Количество открытых квадратных скобок не соответствует кол-ву закрытых нигде.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вас, то при склеивании должно получиться всё-таки

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [7 8 9]
  [3 2 1]
  [1 7 2]]

 [[4 5 6]
  [3 2 1]
  [7 1 5]
  [4 1 8]]]
```

Такого результата можно добиться при помощи numpy.concatenate:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]],
              [[4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1]]])
b = np.array([[[3, 2, 1], [1, 7, 2]],
              [[7, 1, 5], [4, 1, 8]]])
c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
print(c)
```